# How can I safely and dynamically set column names in a query without using %s?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am making a script for a coworker to be able to generate reports from a SQL Server database. I am using pymssql to manage the connection to the database.

My problem is that I want the person using the script to be able to specify which column they want to have returned, as well as the date range they need.

I am using this snippet of code but the column name don't work(from what I understand they get escaped and that is part of the problem) VS typing them out.

```py
if len(columns) == 1:
    query = "SELECT %s FROM dbo.tblPayments WHERE %s < dbo.tblPayments.fldPayDate AND dbo.tblPayments.fldPayDate > %s;"
else:
    query = "SELECT " + ("%s, " * (len(columns) - 1)) + "%s FROM dbo.tblPayments WHERE %s <= dbo.tblPayments.fldPayDate AND dbo.tblPayments.fldPayDate >= %s;"
```

I have seen people saying to use string concatenation with `.format()` instead but I don't want to insert security risks if I can avoid them. Is there something I am missing? What can I do to make it secure?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the columns of a certain table by using the `sys.columns` view. Get the list first and validate the user input in your application using this result. If the column is found you can use it to build the `query`  string.

```
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME ( c.object_id) ='dbo'
AND OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = 'tblPayments'
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. It works well for this script.